# Retina Images with GWT Sprites?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt

I want to use retina images in GWT. I.e., each image which has a retina variant should look like this:

```
logo.png
logo@2x.png
```

I can load retina images with the [RetinaImages](https://github.com/kDCYorke/RetinaImages) lib as:

```
ClientBundleFactory factory = GWT.create(ClientBundleFactory.class);
DemoClientBundle bundle = factory.create();
logoImage.setResource(bundle.logo());
```

The problem is that this only works when using setResource().

I want to use retina images in gwt sprites. For example:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

    ImageResource logo();

    @Source({Css.DEFAULT_CSS })
    Css css();
}
```

and in my css file:

```
@sprite .somePanel {
   gwt-image: "logo";
}
```

This is now working because when using the retina image (logo@2x.png) the image is doubled the size on the screen.

**How can I set the image width and heigh to half in case of a retina image?**

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the pixel size of the image:

```
logoImage.setPixelSize(nominal_width, nominal_height);
```

where nominal width and height are ints defined in a resource file or directly specified in the method call and should be half of the actual image dimensions.

Comment: Please note that you will need the image URL for this to work using logoImage.setResource(bundle.logo().getSafeUri());